# Click on anchor link Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, anchor

Guys I´m facing trouble to click on an anchor ina web site using a VBA code.

The link I want to click is the following:

```
<a href="http://www.hapvida.com.br/pls/webhap/webNewTrocaArquivo.Download?pPessoa=36561410&amp;pNoCache=1817001839&amp;pIdSessao=001718093818134569635">BAIXAR ARQUIVOS - DOWNLOAD</a>
```

I have tried a few methods but they only work for other links on the web site, but not this one.

This is how my code looks right now:

```
Sub login()

    Const Url$ = "https://www.hapvida.com.br/pls/webhap/webNewTrocaArquivo.login"

    Dim UserName As String, Password As String, LoginData As Worksheet
    Set LoginData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1")

    UserName = LoginData.Cells(2, "B").Value
    Password = LoginData.Cells(3, "B").Value

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie

        .Navigate Url
        ieBusy ie
        .Visible = True

        Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object, oCodigo As Object

        Set oLogin = .Document.getElementsByName("pCpf")(0)
        Set oPassword = .Document.getElementsByName("pSenha")(0)

        oLogin.Value = UserName
        oPassword.Value = Password
        .Document.forms(0).submit

    End With

    For Each l In ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("ultimas_noticias")
        If l.tagName = "a" Then
            l.Click
        End If
    Exit For
    Next

End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Where in the supplied html anchor link is there a class name?

Comment: Yes, thats the code form de class name:

Comment: Well, I cannot see the html but I wll offer that you should have another `ieBusy ie` between submitting the login form and looping through the elements in that vclass.

Comment: <div class="ultimas_noticias">
    <span class="titulo"><h1> Troca de Arquivos - Menu Principal</h1></span>
    
(...)

        <a href="http://www.hapvida.com.br/pls/webhap/webNewTrocaArquivo.Download?pPessoa=36561410&amp;pNoCache=1218201830&amp;pIdSessao=201812093018134633856">BAIXAR ARQUIVOS - DOWNLOAD</a>